# Grouping dataframe in 12 groups with same column values

Tags: r, multithreading, dataframe, multidplyr

I have a large dataset with about 15 columns and more than 3 million rows.

Because the dataset is so big, I would like to use `multidplyr`on it .

Because of the data, it would be impossible to just split my data frame to 12 parts. Lets say that there are columns `col1` and `col2` which each have several different values but they repeat (in each column separately).

How can I make 12 (or `n`) similar sized groups which each of them contain rows that have the same value in both `col1` and `col2`?

Example: Lets say one of the possible values in `col1` `foo` and in `col2` is `bar`. Then they would be grouped, all rows with this values would be in one group.

So that the question makes sense, there are always more than 12 unique combinations of `col1` and `col2`.

I would try to do something with for and while loops if this was python but as this is `R`, there probably is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# As you provided no example data, I created some data repeating three times.
# I used dplyr within tidyverse. Then grouped by the columns and sliced 
# the data by chance for n=2. 
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(a=rep(LETTERS,3), b=rep(letters,3))
# the data:
df %>%
   arrange(a,b) %>% 
   group_by(a,b) %>% 
   mutate(n=1:n())
# A tibble: 78 x 3
# Groups:   a, b [26]
        a      b     n
   <fctr> <fctr> <int>
 1      A      a     1
 2      A      a     2
 3      A      a     3
 4      B      b     1
 5      B      b     2
 6      B      b     3
 7      C      c     1
 8      C      c     2
 9      C      c     3
10      D      d     1
# ... with 68 more rows
```

Slicing down the data by chance on two rows per group.

```
set.seed(123)
df %>%
  arrange(a,b) %>% 
  group_by(a,b) %>% 
  mutate(n=1:n()) %>% 
  sample_n(2)
# A tibble: 52 x 3
# Groups:   a, b [26]
        a      b     n
   <fctr> <fctr> <int>
 1      A      a     1
 2      A      a     2
 3      B      b     2
 4      B      b     3
 5      C      c     3
 6      C      c     1
 7      D      d     2
 8      D      d     3
 9      E      e     2
10      E      e     1
# ... with 42 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, but we may have misunderstood each other. I need all of my data to be grouped and I need all of those that are the same together. In this case for n=2, I would need to get 2 groups, similar sized (because the df size is even, around 39), which would include all the elements. So in this case, if we do it alphabetically, all elements from A to including M, and the other group all other elements. Were n=3, one group would be of size 27 (A to I), the other too (J to R), and the other of size 25 (S to Z).

Comment: @Ravonrip Sorry, I don't get it. Please edit your question and include some reproducible data and your expected output. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997162/function-dividing-a-number-in-n-integer-with-app-same-size) as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create sample data 
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a=rep(LETTERS,3), b=rep(letters,3), 
             nobs=sample(1:100, 26*3,replace=T), stringsAsFactors=F)

# Get all unique combinations of col1 and col2
combos <- df %>%
  group_by(a,b) %>% 
  summarize(n=sum(nobs)) %>% 
  as.data.frame(.) 

top12 <- combos %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  top_n(12,n)
top12

l <- list()
for(i in 1:11){
  l[[i]] <- combos[combos$a==top12[i,"a"] & combos$b==top12[i,"b"],]
}

l[[12]] <- combos %>% 
  anti_join(top12,by=c("a","b")) 
l

# This produces a list 'l' that contains twelve data frames -- the top 11 most-commonly occuring pairs of col1 and col2, and all the rest of the data in the 12th list element.
```